# PIDs and associator rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and let $p \in R$ be prime. Show that the quotient $R/\langle p^k\rangle$ is an associator ring for any positive integer $k$ - that is, if $a, b \in R/\langle p^k\rangle$ generate the same ideal, then there exists a unit $u$ in $R/\langle p^k\rangle$ with $a=ub$ in this ring.

Comment: So "associator ring" means every two generators of a given principal ideal are unit multiples of one another?  (I only got 5 hits in google, and I couldn't get to a definition in any of them.)

Comment: In my experience, they are usually called strongly associate rings. 
 This gives some background: http://journals.math.tku.edu.tw/index.php/TKJM/article/viewFile/464/396

Answer (score 1):

This property that $(a)=(b)$ implies $a=\lambda b$ for some unit $\lambda \in U(R)$ is called a strongly associate ring usually in my experience.  Any ring which is presimplifiable has this property.  I believe this kind of ring is called a Special Principal Ideal Ring.  This kind of thing is studied here in a paper by Anderson, Axtell, Forman, and Stickles called When are associates unit multiples?: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38371302_When_are_Associates_Unit_Multiples